# Xcode Call a function from another .h file to update it's status

Tags: iphone, xcode, class, uiviewcontroller, mapkit

I have two UIView and link to the following files
1. FirstViewController.h and .m
2. MapTypeOption.h and .m

FirstViewController is link to MapTypeOption with Navigation control

I would like to perform the following task
Use a UI Segment Control at MapTypeOption to change
the Google map type in FirstViewController

so in FirstViewController.h I have a function as follow

```
- (void)ChangeMapType:(int )SelectIndex
```

my FirstViewController.m has a function as follow

```
-(void)ChangeMapType:(int )SelectIndex
{
    switch (SelectIndex) 
    {
    case 0:
        MainMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        break;
    case 1:
        MainMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
        break;
    case 2:
        MainMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
        break;

    default:
        MainMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        break;
    }
}
```

in MapTypeOption.m I have the following

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@class FirstViewController;
....
- (IBAction)updatemaptype:(id)sender 
{
    FirstViewController *newFirstViewControllerobj=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [newFirstViewControllerobj ChangeMapType:MapTypeSegment.selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

I can compile and run my program (with simulator) but even I select a different
segment at MapTypeOption view nothing is changed in FirstViewController

Comment: You are creating a whole new instance of FirstViewController. So in essence you are changing the properties of the newly created FirstViewController. What you need to do is pass the "original"FirstViewController to your MapTypeOption somehow.

Comment: I am thinking, 1.somehow I need a direct access from MapTypeOption to FirstViewControl.  2. Or I have to declare a Global Variable which is not in FirstViewController or MapChangeOption but they both can access it. 3.pass variable or status when I nevigate back. Thanks for your comment @HubertKunnemeyer

Comment: Yes, You need to add a property for the FirstViewController to your MapTypeOption.h then when you push or add the MapTypeOption set it something like: [MapTypeOption.firstViewController = self];

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call [view setNeedsDisplay] in ChangeMapType to cause the view to update.